# Compare single array to individual arrays in array of arrays using for loop/fucntion python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, time-series, dtw

I apologise for the tounge-twister of a title.

To summarise, I am trying to apply dtw to a dataframe of tree-ring series I have. I want to be able to apply dtw to each column, comparing each to the rest in the dataset, but it's just figuiring out the logic, that's getting me confused - I now have a single array 9one column) and an array of arrays I want to compare it to individually (the other columns) - as I have 46 columns, It's going to take a monumentous amount of time to manually do this. So I'm looking for a way that will print the distances between each column.

I have my single array ie, column 1 (a1):

```
array([2231.121954586618, 2191.32688635395, 2153.33037342928,
       2167.460745065675, 2182.327272147529, 2148.104497944283,
       2114.629371754906, 2093.254599793933, 2013.228738264795,
       1960.124018035272, 1956.115012446374, 2004.772102502964,
       1996.031697793075, 1984.117922837165, 1927.018245950742,
       1889.983294062236, 1857.106663618318, 1855.521387844768,
       1854.30527162405, 1843.946144942001, 1834.918111326537,
       1786.367506785417, 1764.596236951255, 1765.789120636587,
       1768.225728544412, 1801.390137110182, 1820.438710725669,
       1821.776101512033, 1814.626915671021, 1789.410699262131,
       1752.680382970908, 1774.240633213347, 1793.576383615812,
       1802.430943044276, 1810.653920721653, 1832.59203921635,
       1836.215188930494, 1804.727265942576, 1807.798802135772,
       1853.273004232627, 1875.641068893134, 1880.352238594259,
       1845.111091114404, 1807.281434172499, 1802.326163448382,
       1779.565520429905, 1827.148896035324, 1860.634653074935],
      dtype=object)
```

and array of arrays, ie columns 2:46 (a1_compare):

```
array([[2338.980748451803, 2313.115476761541, 2266.320969548615, ...,
        1971.777882561555, 2004.912406403344, 2005.090872507429],
       [5085.120869045766, 4994.508983933459, 4926.377921200292, ...,
        3810.539158921751, 3757.139414193585, 3698.921580852207],
       [1441.5932022738868, 1441.5932022738868, 250.2478024965511, ...,
        2864.532339498514, 2775.946234841519, 2764.567521984336],
       ...,
       [822.4370926086343, 848.1167402384477, 887.7301546370533, ...,
        1549.347739499023, 1592.226581401639, 1577.883355154341],
       [1508.596325796503, 1593.192415483712, 1587.73520115259, ...,
        1467.943298815971, 1556.004468001763, 1528.921150058964],
       [1300.0305814488, 1369.177320180398, 1480.576904436118, ...,
        1379.66588731831, 1367.312665162758, 1328.830519316272]],
      dtype=object)
```

and finally my code to attempt to compare them:

```
def compare1(array1, array_arrays):
for i in array_arrays:
    distance, path = fastdtw(a1, i, dist = manhattan_distance)
return distance
```

But this is only returning one value:

```
compare1(a1, a1_compare)

12271.277
```

when I want it to be each individual - the first is: 4164.2393701224755 but I want all the others too. Any suggestions as to how I can do this without having to individually compare each column/array?

Comment: could you edit your question to make sure all your indentation is correctly represented? As-is the `compare1` function is improperly indented, and it seems like that may have been a mistake in copying over your code.

Comment: on an unrelated note, is there a reason you're using `dtype=object` rather than `float`?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your problem correctly, your for loop computes and then over-writes `distance` for each sub array in `a1_compare` until the last iteration when the value of only the last one is returned. There are many ways to save the results of every iteration, but the most sensible to me is to allocate an empty array the same length as `a1_compare` and save `distance` to the appropriate index of the output array each iteration:

```
def compare1(array1, array_arrays):
    distances = np.empty(len(array_arrays)) #create an empty container the right size
    #enumerate is an easy way to get an index at the same time as the value itself.
    for i, value in enumerate(array_arrays): 
        distance, path = fastdtw(a1, value, dist = manhattan_distance)
        distances[i] = distance #save our results
    return distances #return all of them
```